# Can't assign a default user_role="ROLE_USER" with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a user model and I am triyng to set a default role="role_user" in my postgreSQL database when a user register.  My User model is:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@NotEmpty(message = "Campul nu poate fi lasat gol")
@Size(min = 4, max = 16,message = "Dimensiunea trebuie sa fie intre 4 si 16 caractere")
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty(message = "Campul nu poate fi lasat gol")
@Size(min = 4, max = 16,message = "Dimensiunea trebuie sa fie intre 4 si 16 caractere")
private String lastName;

@Id
@NotEmpty(message = "Campul nu poate fi gol")
@Email(message = "Email-ul trebuie sa fie valid")
private String email;

@NotEmpty(message = "Campul nu poate fi gol")
@Size(min = 4, max = 60, message = "Parola trebuie sa contina minim 4 caractere")
private String password;

private String role;

private boolean enabled = true;

public User() {};
public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password,String role) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.role = role;

}
```

How can I solve the problem. I saw another posts on stackoverflow but I don't understand, I'm quite new in Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just initialize your field with the default value.

```
private String role = "role_user";

public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password,String role) {
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.lastName = lastName;
     this.email = email;
     this.password = password;
     if(role != null) { this.role = role; }; // if you need to keep the default value
 }
```